# RXJS 'never' subject as the generic type

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am working with RXJS and Typescript in an angular project. I have written the following in my code:

```
const sub = new Subject<never>();
```

I expect this line to mean that any subscriber that defines the 'next' and 'error' methods, as can be seen below, will never have the 'next' method called. Only the 'error' method will be called, if at all.

```
sub.subscribe(() => /*do something with 'next' value*/, error => /*do something with 'error' value*/)
```

However, when I write the following:

```
sub.next();
```

I do not get a compilation error.

From my understanding the Subject generic is the type returned by the subject, so never means that we never call the next method.

Can anyone explain why? Is this a bug, a feature or misunderstanding on my part?

Comment: You want to everytime one subscribe that subject, it will get error right ?

Comment: @HungCung, yes and I want to have an error in the case someone writes: sub.next()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifying the type param on your Subject does restrict the type of value that you can pass when you call `.next()`, so if you attempt to pass a value: `sub.next('string value')` you will get an error:

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.(2345)

However, the `value` parameter of [`Subject.next()`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.x/src/internal/Subject.ts#L61) is optional (*in RxJS v6*).  This means, calling `sub.next()` without passing argument is allowed, so you can call `Subject.next` with both an argument of type `T` or with no argument at all.

---

I believe this behavior has changed in RxJS v7. [Interesting GitHub Issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2852#issuecomment-798892138)

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/subject.md#void-subject

Answer (score 2):

It looks like for `Subject<T>` the `next` method is defined like this: `next(val: T | undefined): void`, so you can always pass undefined into it. This is different to `BehaviorSubject` for example, where the signature is `next(val: T): void` and trying to call `next` will produce a compile-time error.

I'm not sure why this is the case.

Comment: So 'never' means no value should ever be returned and the reason we can still get a value is the addition of the 'undefined'. Definition seems a bit off for Subject type....

Comment: Yep agreed, as pointed out in the other answer, this issue https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2852#issuecomment-798892138 seems to have fixed the problem as of rxjs v7